# Reach John to top

Tags: c++, algorithm

#### Problem Statement

John wants to climb up a stair of n steps. He can climb 1 or 2 steps at each move. John wants the number of moves to be a multiple of an integer m.

What is the minimal number of steps making him climb to the top of the stairs that satisfies his condition?

#### Input

The single line contains two space separated integers n, m (0 < n ≤ 10000, 1 < m ≤ 10).

#### Output

Print a single integer — the minimal steps being a multiple of m. If there is no way he can climb satisfying condition print  - 1 instead.

#### Sample test(s)

```
Input

10 2

Output

6

Input

3 5

Output

-1
```

#### Notes:

For the first sample, John could climb in 6 moves with following sequence of steps: {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}.

For the second sample, there are only three valid sequence of steps {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1, 1} with 2, 2, and 3 steps respectively. All these numbers are not multiples of 5.

#### My code:

I have been trying to solve this problem ,so i thought of using nearest power of 2 less than the given number but got wrong answer

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int n,m;
  scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
  int x= pow (2,floor (log2(n)) );
  int rem = n-x;
  int ans = ((x/2)+rem);
  if ( ans % m == 0 )
    printf (" %d \n ",ans);
  else
    printf("-1\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please update the title of your question, it does not properly reflect the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't see how the powers of two are useful at all.

Let's write a different algorithm in pseudocode first:

```
N = number of steps
M = desired multiple

# Excluding any idea of the multiple restraint, what is the maximum and minimum
# number of steps that John could take?

If number of steps is even:
    minimum = N / 2
    maximum = N

If number of steps is odd:
    minimum = N / 2 + 1
    maximum = N

# Maybe the minimum number of steps is perfect?

If minimum is a multiple of M:
    Print minimum

# If it isn't, then we need to increase the number of steps up to a multiple of M.
# We then need to make sure that it didn't surpass the maximum number of steps.

Otherwise:
    goal = minimum - (minimum % M) + M

    if goal <= maximum:
        Print goal
    Otherwise:
        Print -1
```

We can then convert this to code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    const int minimum = (n / 2) + (n % 2);
    const int maximum = n;

    if (minimum % m == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", minimum);
        return 0;
    }

    const int guess = minimum - (minimum % m) + m;
    if (guess <= maximum) {
        printf("%d\n", guess);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%d\n", -1);
    return 0;
}
```

The key tool that I'm using here is that I know that John can scale the stairs in any combination of steps between (and including) `[minimum, maximum]`. How can we determine this?

1. We know the minimum number of steps is using 2 at a time as much as possible.
2. We know the maximum number of steps is using 1 at a time.
3. We know that if the current number of steps is not the maximum, then we can replace one of the steps (that must be using 2 at a time) and replace it with taking each step one at a time. That would increase the total number of steps by 1.

Comment: @user111: I'm fairly sure the algorithm in your original question is simply wrong. Does the algorithm / code that I'm showing here give the correct answer? If not, can you tell me a case where you get the wrong answer?

Comment: `2 2`  your program gives `-1`  but answer should be 2   @sharth

Comment: @user111: You're correct! In my description I said _inclusive_, but I messed that up in the translation to code. It should be fixed now.